# TCL mysqltcl for 64bit windows platform

Tags: mysql, tcl

I need to updated few field of mysql database using the result from tcl program.
I downloaded the mysqltcl from http://www.xdobry.de/mysqltcl/windows.html 
I read a note here that the dlls (`libmysqltcl.dll` & `libmysql.dll`) are not compatible to 64 bit windows.

I gave it a try and it gives error when i tried to use the `load` it throws below error.

```
couldn't load library "libmysqltcl.dll": invalid argument
```

I googled a bit and many had similar problems. I tried modifying the `pkgIndex.tcl` but it didn't work. Finally I need to write this here to see if anyone can guide to install the mysqltcl package on windows 64bit.

Comment: 64-bit EXEs and 32-bit DLLs won't work together. Ever.

Comment: Please advise how to get a 64bit dll for libmysqltcl.dll & libmysql.dll.Thanks!!

Comment: or advice a tck package which can run on windws 64 to link to mysql. thanks